# Upload file using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a form that I am sending to the server using jQuery `$.post` method. I am sending several fields with something like:

```
var myName = "Pedro";
var myDescription = "Description of Pedro";

$.post("~/insert_user", { name: myName, description: myDescription }, function(data){
    alert("Successfully inserted " + data.name + " in DB");
}, "json");
```

This works great, as I take the values in `insert_user.php` and treat and insert the in the data base.

What if I need to add a  field to my form to let the user upload an image?

How would I do that in my `$.post` call and how would I get it in the PHP?

I am using Symfony2.0, by the way, just in case it changes something. But the important part is how to add a file typed field to the ajax call.

Thanks in advance.

Pedro

Comment: Send the path of that image to `insert_user.php` through ajax and perform file_upload there

Comment: And how the insert_user.php would access file on user system?

Comment: I don't think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will find it would be a lot easier to use a pre built jquery plugin. My favourite is uploadify http://uploadify.com.

Its simple and easy to use and it will save you a lot of time trying to figure out a method of your own  <>

$.post is the same as the code block bellow. In order for you to do what you need to you need to change it to use this atleast and then things will become simpler. So start by changing the $.post to this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Then add a parameter in the ajax block contentType : "multipart/form-data" or try mimeType (cant remember so clearly) and in the data : $("#form").serialize(), that should work.

please tell me if it didn't work

--NEW EDIT LOL-- Excuse my blind coding, you may need to test this

I did a bit more research and came across this. You need to build this array and add it to the data in your ajax block

```
var files = new FormData($('#fileinputid'));     
jQuery.each($('#fileinputid')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    files.append(i, file);
});
```

If what i read was accurate you should be able to pass that array with the rest of the ajax data. Although i am not completely sure how to add it to the serialized data.

Please test this and let me know. if it doesn't work ill do a full javascript script test for you and then post it here

Comment: Thank you. But the question is how to combine an already working $.post call with the submitting of a file (an image in this case). I don't really realize how to do it.

Comment: Ok. now I am getting it all much better :). Well, I have passed to a $.ajax model and all keeps working. So stage 1 succeeded. The problem now is this: (from jQuery documentation) "Data from file select elements is not serialized." So when I go $("#myForm").serialize(), it does not serializes the image data. So... any other advice?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and effort. I finally used this library to get to pass the file to the server http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq. I exactly explains what I needed. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help: [Nettuts+: Uploading Files With AJAX](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/)

Comment: Thank you. But the question is how to combine an already working $.post call with the submitting of a file (an image in this case). I don't really realize how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make iframe and put form in it, submit the form and voila. Or you can use one of these [AJAX File upload scripts](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/)

Comment: Thank you. But the question is how to combine an already working $.post call with the submitting of a file (an image in this case). I don't really realize how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq

It just works great for what I need.

Thank you guys for your help.